# C# Best Practise: Code within the form or create a class and call its methods?

Tags: c#

Is it better to create a class then call the class methods from the form using controls as parameters or put all the methods within the form?

Comment: ...depends on the code.  the form can handle much of the trivial stuff and events related to user interaction.  Managing the resulting *data* should usually be left to a class; that doesnt have to require passing controls to the class though

Answer (score 2):

of course it is better to create a class : it's separation of concern (view / model).